# Custom reference mapping in Fluent Nhibernate

Tags: .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, composite-key

In my database, I have two tables, one logically referencing other, but with no foreign key defined (I cannot control the database, so have to live with that). E.g.:

```
Table1 (
    Table1Id int,
    Column1 int,
    Column2 int
)

Table2 (
    Table2Id int,
    Column1FromTable1 int,
    Column2FromTable1 int
)
```

Suppose there is guarantee that `(Column1, Column2)` pair is unique for `Table1`.

In the code, I want to define `HasMany` mapping for `Table1`, like this:

```
public class Table1
{
    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Table2> Table2s
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Table2
{
    public int Id
    {

    }

    public Table1 Table1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}

public class Table1Map : ClassMap<Table1>
{
    public Table1Map()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("Table1Id");
        HasMany(x => x.Table2s); //What next?
    }
}
```

What do I have to do for that? What methods of `OneToManyPart` can I use to define the reference?

In simple words, with Fluent NHibernate, how do I tie in the code entities that are not tied in the database? The problem is also in the complex key that I have to use here.

Again, I cannot change the database in this case, which would be my natural choice otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to map `Col1` & `Col2` as a composite key like that:

```
public class Table1Map : ClassMap<Table1>
{
    public Table1Map()
    {
        UseCompositeId()  
                .WithKeyProperty( x => x.Column1 , "Column1" )  
                .WithKeyProperty( x => x.Column2 , "Column2" );  
        HasMany(x => x.Table2s)
                 .WithKeyColumn( "Column1FromTable1" )  
                 .WithKeyColumn( "Column2FromTable1" ) ;
        Map(x => x.Id).Column("Table1Id");
    }
}
```

and in the mapping for `Table2`:

```
public class Table2Map : ClassMap<Table2>
{
    public Table2Map()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("Table2Id");
        References(x => x.Table1)
                 .WithColumns( "Column1FromTable1", "Column2FromTable1" ) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This definitely looks correct, yet I have a long way to go before I can really test my mappings, so I will remember to accept your answer later, when the mapping is proven to work.

Comment: And one more question then: I will need to add Column1 and Column2 to Table1 class definition, there is no way to avoid that, is there?

Comment: Nope, sorry, this did not work as I expected. Namely, this totally overrides real `Table1` id and everywhere further considers `Table11` to have composite id. Namely, when I call `Session.Get<Table1>(1)`, it fails with `InvalidCastException` with message "System.Int32". This means that it expects id to be a composite object and receives int, which causes the exception. That is definitely not what I need. Thank you anyway!

Comment: You are right, this assumes the com[osite key as the primary key of Table1. I don't know how to map a composite key as a secondary key that can be references using `propertyRef` . Perhaps you can find a solution to do it with hbm mappings.